# Repeating the same task concurrent in a changing amount of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I've got a graphic in a JavaFX GUI, which I want animated.

As you probably know, you can't change a JavaFX GUI outside of the main thread, so to imitate animation you have to create a worker thread, which then feeds Runnables to the main thread.

Now my goal is to animate different parts of the graphic at the same time asynchronously, while being able to change the amount of how many at a time, as well as the delay. I added sliders for that to the GUI.

I solved this problem by creating a 'ThreadSpawner' which in turn created n amounts of threads (which then died, after completing their task once).

```
    Task<Void> spawner = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws InterruptedException {

            while () {
                for (int n = 0; n < amount; n++) {
                    Thread th = new Thread(task);
                    th.setDaemon(true);
                    th.start();
                }
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(spawner);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
```

However, I neither like the look of it, nor is the performance all too good.

I looked into [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) as well, but those don't like the idea of changing the amount of threads or the delay on the fly.

What would be faster? What would be better? Are there other approaches I didn't think of?
My solutions just seem way too complicated for such a 'basic' task.

Answer (score 0):

So for changing the number of threads, the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) has a method called [setCorePoolSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize(int)), which will allow you to change the number of threads.  (Note: this is NOT in the interface!)

As for changing the frequency, the best thing to do is to call `cancel` on the future you received from the first scheduler, and then add again with the new frequency.

Comment: There's no way around filling the Executor with as many tasks as maximum possible threads, is there? I guess I'll just shift the sleep into the task, to avoid all that canceling and submitting. Other than that, setCorePoolSize helps a lot. Should have looked at inherited methods. Thanks!